Movie with spiral staircase towards heaven
I am searching a movie my girlfriend told me about that she watched as a kid some twenty years ago. She lived in Russia at the time, but it probably was not a Russian movie.
It featured a spiral staircase that was built towards heaven. It was built by a family with a boy who had some illness. He always screamed when something was not in order. In a particular scene, a man wore a cap the wrong way round, and the boy would only stop screaming when the man turned the cap.
The staircase was probably built with the intention to save the boy. My girlfriend remembers vaguely that the mother of the boy had a nightmare of going up the staircase while it starts shaking and brakes. 
Can somebody identify the movie?

Was this an animated film?

Sounds like House of Cards (1993)

The story begins in Mexico, where a little girl named Sally Matthews (Asha Menina) lives with her parents, scientists studying ancient ruins. When her father falls to his death, Sally is comforted by a Mayan mystic that tells Sally her father has gone to the moon. When Sally, her mother Ruth (Kathleen Turner), and her brother Michael (Shiloh Strong) return home to North Carolina, Sally begins to retreat into autism. She first stares silently at the night sky. Then she shrieks when Ruth wears a baseball cap the wrong way. Finally she develops the habit of scaling the roof of the house and other tall structures. This makes Ruth realize that there is something seriously wrong, and she takes her to see Dr. Jacob Beerlander, a psychiatrist who is an expert in autism. As Sally retreats more and more into herself, Beerlander and Ruth clash over the scientific approach versus the intuition of a mother.




